# building a higher order component for `Field` redux component

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a `Field` component and I want to build a new `CurrencyField`

old `Field` component

```
<Field
    component={FormField}
    id="amount"
    label="Amount"
    type="text"
    name="amount"
    {...currencyMask}
    maxLength={16}
    valid={}
    validate={[
        required(),
        length({ max: 13 }),
        numericality({ '>': 0, msg: 'Must be greater than 0!' }),
        numericality({ '<=': loan.AccountBalance, msg: `Must be less than or equal to customer's account balance of $${loan.AccountBalance}` }),
    ]}
/>
```

new `CurrencyField` equivalent to `Field` above that I want to look like this:

```
<CurrencyField
    id="amount"
    label="Amount"
    type="text"
    name="amount"
/>
```

or

```
<Field
    component={CurrencyField}
    id="amount"
    label="Amount"
    type="text"
    name="amount"
/>
```

I get errors when I try to do this:

```
export const CurrencyField = (props) => {

  return (
    <Field
      name={props.input.name}
      type={props.type || "text"}
      maxLength={16}
      {...props}
      validate={[
        required(),
        length({ max: 11 }),
        numericality({ '>': 0, msg: 'Must be greater than 0!' })
      ]}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the ***component*** attribute in your new ***Field*** component in CurrencyField stateless function

Answer (score 2):

What errors you got?

Also you should move validate function outside of the render https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/4017

```
const validateCurrency = [
    required(),
    length({ max: 11 }),
    numericality({ '>': 0, msg: 'Must be greater than 0!' })
 ]
export const CurrencyField = (props) => {
    return (
      <Field
         name={props.input.name}
         type={props.type || "text"}
         maxLength={16}
         {...props}
         validate={validateCurrency}
      />
    );
}
```

Comment: forgot the component attribute!!! took me the whole day to not see that!